# Images appear on one page, but not on another page that uses almost the exact same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched everywhere for help on this, but the only answers I come up with are to the question of why an image won't show up *at all.*  Here is my problem:

In my Rails CRM app, I created a scaffold for "Contacts."  I purchased a template on ThemeForest that uses Bootstrap, and have copied all the CSS and javascript files into my Vendor directory.  The template comes with a number of HTML files.  I selected one and used it as my main Contacts List.  I used the "datatables.net" gem to display the contact list.  This particular HTML file contains a number of images, mainly used for buttons.  All the images display correctly on this page.

On my Edit Contacts page, I copied and pasted all of the HTML from the Contact List page, and inserted a Form For partial in place of the contact list table to display editable fields for a particular contact.  At first, all of the images on this page did not work.  I did some reading about the asset pipeline, and discovered that the image source should be  "asset/image_name.png" instead of "images/image_name.png".  (I had copied all my images to the assets/images folder.)  I was puzzled why the images on the main contact list page would work, but the Edit page would not.  Regardless, I did a find and replace for "/images/" and replaced it with "/assets/".  This fixed about 2/3 of the images on the Edit Contacts page.  The rest, I am still getting the following error as an example on Rails Server:

Started GET "/contacts/assets/icons/quickstats/user.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-15 23:40:42 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/contacts/assets/icons/quickstats/user.png"):

This is the same error I got before I did the find/replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are probably using "assets/blah.png" instead of "/assets/blah.png". This will work for root urls but not for anything deeper, eg. "/contacts/new".

Instead of typing the URL out, use the image_tag helper, which will take care of this stuff for you.